# Why only one core is taking all the load , how to make other 29 cores to take load?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to push my Spark processed data to 3 node cluster of C*. I am pushing 200 million records to Cassandra it is failing with below err.

Below it the my spark cluster configuration

```
Nodes : 12
vCores Total : 112
Total memory : 1.5 TB.
Below are my spark-sumbit parameters:

$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit 
--master yarn 
--deploy-mode cluster 
--name app 
--class Driver 
--executor-cores 3 
--executor-memory 8g 
--num-executors 10 
--driver-cores 2 
--driver-memory 10g 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false 
--conf spark.task.maxFailures=8  
--conf spark.ui.killEnabled=false 
 oracle2c.jar
```

I have made the Spark data frame partitions 30 as below

```
+--------------------+-------+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|  count|
+--------------------+-------+
|                  22|6687176|
|                  29|6687175|
|                   8|6687176|
|                  21|6687176|
|                  23|6687176|
|                   5|6687176|
|                   9|6687176|
|                  17|6687176|
|                  26|6687175|
|                  27|6687175|
|                   4|6687176|
|                  10|6687176|
|                  18|6687176|
|                  25|6687175|
|                   1|6687176|
|                  20|6687176|
|                  12|6687176|
|                  28|6687175|
|                  24|6687176|
|                  15|6687176|
|                  14|6687176|
|                   6|6687176|
|                  19|6687176|
|                   0|6687175|
|                   3|6687176|
|                  11|6687176|
|                   2|6687176|
|                   7|6687176|
|                  13|6687176|
|                  16|6687176|
+--------------------+-------+
```

But when I run the job I see only one core in executor is running , how to make all the cores take part of load distribution?

[image]

What more configuration parameters I need to add to make all the cores take the load ?

Comment: do you have an spark executor on every C* node? Like explained here https://opencredo.com/deploy-spark-apache-cassandra/ on *Design the deployment*

Comment: @Joss No , we have 3 node C* cluster on a different nodes all together and 12 node spark cluster on different nodes.... not able to understand what exactly you are trying to convey here.

Comment: @AlexOtt , sir can you please advice on this issue ? my spark job , load is taken by only one core , even thought number of partitions & 29 other cores available.

Comment: How are you loading the data to Cassandra? Can you make use of `foreachPartition`? So that each partition will run parallelly based on the available cores. @user3252097

Comment: @BhimaRaoGogineni """ val numOfPartitions = 20 /// read from property file
val new_df= org_df.repartition(numOfPartitions)

new_df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(Map( "table" -> cFName, "keyspace" -> keyspace ))
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save()   """"

Comment: @BhimaRaoGogineni how to use foreachPartition with new datastax connector api ... any sample please ?

Comment: @user3252097 I don't have any sample code. Check any write options are available with datastax connector API. Or you can try the rdd api instead of dataframe API while writing the data to Cassandra.

Comment: @BhimaRaoGogineni thank you

Comment: @mrsrinivas , can you please help me with this issue?