# Unable to filter parquet file using where clause.... error "unsafe symbol Unstable"

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, databricks, parquet-mr

I am unable to fiter give parquet file.

I have dataframe with "family_id" of String and "lastStagedTs" of Date type. i.e. 2018-11-30 in format.

I am trying to filter the parquet file like below i.e. select data which is greater than 2018-11-23

```
  val lastRun:String = "2018-11-23"  
  val parquetDf = sparkSession.read.format("parquet")
                                .load(parquetFile) 
                                .select("family_id", "lastStagedTs")
                                .where($"lastStagedTs" > lastRun)
```

When I'm running above line of code I getting the below error:

```
unsafe symbol Unstable (child of <none>) in runtime reflection universe
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:205)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TypeSymbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:3030)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a spark dataframe based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994997/filtering-a-spark-dataframe-based-on-date)

Comment: Everything looks good except where part `.where(s"lastStagedTs > '${lastRun}'")`

Comment: @BhimaRaoGogineni thank you so much Bhima. Can I filter the query while loading the parquet file itself ? if so how ??? val lastRun:String = "2018-11-23"  
  val parquetDf = sparkSession.read.format("parquet").where(????) 
                                .load(parquetFile)

Comment: @BhimaRaoGogineni can you please check this , you might know what am I doing wrong here .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53442130/why-only-one-core-is-taking-all-the-load-how-to-make-other-29-cores-to-take-lo?noredirect=1#comment93765295_53442130

Comment: Even if you have the filter after the load also no problem. Since spark uses predictive pushdown. Our filter condition will be applied before loading the data itself. @user3252097

Comment: @BhimaRaoGogineni but we have two statements ...one is load() after that filter.... cant it be run two stages ...by the time we filter already is data is loaded into the dataframe right ?

Comment: Ya, that is correct but spark loads the data lazily. The `load` is a transformation and filter also transformation. So it can apply the filter before loading the data itself and data format is parquet. It takes advantage of parquet format. @user3252097