# "expression is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function" what is wrong here?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to apply a pivot on my dataframe as below

```
val pivot_company_model_vals_df =  company_model_vals_df.groupBy("company_id","id","date")
                          .pivot("code")
                          .agg( when( col("data_item_value_numeric").isNotNull,  
      first("numeric")).otherwise(first("value")) )
```

Error

```
         org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression '`data_item_value_numeric`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function.
```

Could you please help me what am I doing wrong here?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue fixed moving the `first` like below `.agg( first(when`:

```
val pivot_company_model_vals_df =  company_model_vals_df.groupBy("company_id","model_id","data_date")
                          .pivot("code")
                          .agg( first(when( col("data_item_value_numeric").isNotNull,  
      col("numeric")).otherwise(col("_string")) ) )
```

Comment: @SCouto , sir i fixed the issue using agg function first() but some of the data is coming wrong example value "0.00008" coming as "8.0E-5"  ...how should I handle it ?

Comment: 8.0e-5 os exactly the same as 0.00008. it's a Matter of how the Data is shown. If You want yo show It without he exponential You an use f"$yourvariable%1.5f with 1 being the number of digits before the decimal point, and 5 the digits after it. More info here https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-format-numbers-commas-international-currency-in-scala

Comment: @eliasah with col , how I get value of the column ?